# Как правильно получить AddressOfEntryPoint?

Tags: c++, winapi, pe

Получаю адрес модуля и адрес функции main почему они не соответсвуют AddressOfEntryPoint?

```
int main() {

    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hModule;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)hModule + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);

    printf("hModule: 0x%llx\n", hModule);    
    //0x7ff6a9790000 

    printf("main: 0x%llx\n", main); 
    //0x7ff6a9792ea0

    printf("AddressOfEntryPoint: %lx\n", pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
    //0x41a8

    return 0;
}
```

адрес hModule равен  0x7ff6a9790000, адрес main равен  0x7ff6a9792ea0

0x7ff6a9792ea0 - 0x7ff6a9790000 = 0x2ea0

а AddressOfEntryPoint равен 0x41a8 почему он не равен 0x2ea0?

Так же если делать по формуле EP(File) = AddressOfEntryPoint – BaseOfCode + .text[PointerToRawData] + FileAlignment

```
int text = 0;

printf("EP File: %x\n", pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint - (pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.BaseOfCode + pSectHeader[text].PointerToRawData + pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.FileAlignment)

//AddressOfEntryPoint:41b8
//BaseOfCode:1000
//PointerToRawData:400
//FileAlignment:200
```

0x41b8 - (0x1000 + 0x400 + 0x200) = 0x2bb8 что тоже не равно 0x2ea0

В чём ошибка? Как правильно посчитать?

Comment: Функция `main` не является точкой входа. На самом деле выполнение начинается с совсем другого кода, который выполняет начальную инициализацию и лишь потом вызывается `main`. Вот тут можно почитать об этом подробнее: https://habr.com/ru/post/339698/ (там про Linux, но в Windows должно быть примерно то же самое).

Comment: действительно проверил на дебагере, вы правы